# No framework detected when deploying a subdirectory to Azure Web App via GitHub Actions

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, github-actions, cicd, kudu

I'm using Github to deploy a flask app into an Azure web app. I configured CI/CD with GitHub Actions through Azure following these [setup instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-github-actions?tabs=applevel) through the deployment centre which automatically created a workflow for me in my repo.

I have my frontend deployed separately and only want to deploy the backend folder via GitHub Actions and to the Azure web app (basically just want to deploy a subdirectory of my repo).

My repo structure is organized like so:

```
my-repo
├── .github/workflows       # workflow file for GH actions
├── backend                 # my flask app that I want to deploy
│   ├── requirements.txt          
│   └── ...
└── ...                     # other files and frontend stuff I don't want deployed
```

Here is my workflow file:

```
# Docs for the Azure Web Apps Deploy action: https://github.com/Azure/webapps-deploy
# More GitHub Actions for Azure: https://github.com/Azure/actions
# More info on Python, GitHub Actions, and Azure App Service: https://aka.ms/python-webapps-actions

name: Build and deploy Python app to Azure Web App - xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:

  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      working_directory: "backend/"

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Python version
        uses: actions/setup-python@v1
        with:
          python-version: '3.11'

      - name: Create and start virtual environment
        run: |
          python -m venv venv
          source venv/bin/activate
        working-directory: "backend/"
      
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: pip install -r requirements.txt
        working-directory: "backend/"
        
      # Optional: Add step to run tests here (PyTest, Django test suites, etc.)
      
      - name: Upload artifact for deployment jobs
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          working_directory: "backend/"
          name: python-app
          path: |
            ./backend/
            !venv/

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: python-app
          path: ./backend/
          
      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        with:
          app-name: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx }}
```

Upon deployment via GitHub Actions I am successfully able to build and deploy but I get `No framework detected; using default app from /opt/defaultsite` and `Generating gunicorn command for 'application:app'` on my Azure web app deployment logs, and then the app does not work (backend is not properly deployed). When I deploy manually through VS code and the Azure App Service extension this does not happen and instead I get `Detected an app based on Flask` and `Generating gunicorn command for 'app:app'` which is correct and then my app works. In this manual version I'm able to manually select which folder to upload for deployment.

[image: Azure web app logs]

I suspect it is something with uploading artifacts where it's unable to find my backend folder (the subdirectory). What's confusing is that I turned debug mode on for GitHub actions deployment and it's able to find the `requirements.txt` and seems to be able to find my backend files when uploading artifacts. Here is a snippet from the debug logs:

```
##[debug]File:/home/runner/work/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/backend/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/__pycache__/hash.cpython-311.pyc was found using the provided searchPath
```

I've tried a couple different ways to set the `working-directory` as `backend/` like:

1. Setting it at each step to use the path or working-directory specified
2. Adding in a step at the beginning of all steps to `cd backend`
3. Adding a `.deployment` file into the root of my repo with this content:

```
[config]
project = /backend
```

But all trials have resulted in the same issue (no framework detected).

Would appreciate any ideas and help!

Comment: Not sure if it's directly related to your issue; but, in the `build` job, you need to run `source venv/bin/activate` again before `pip install`. Each `run` is a separate shell. An activated `venv` won't be activated in the next one automatically. You may combine both steps if that's fine with you.

Comment: @Azeem Gotcha! just added `source venv/bin/activate && pip install -r requirements.txt` to the `Install dependencies` step, made the build time a lot longer but unfortunately still had the same "No framework detected" log. It's weird that the Azure default workflow didn't have that step set at default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are deploying app from a sub folder, you need to mention your path in the `'Deploy to Azure Web App'` in the `package` section in your `workflow.yml` file.

As Mentioned in the [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-github-actions?tabs=applevel#python) in `pacakage` path is taken from the environemt. I have just added the path to `./backend`.

Also you need to add this setting in the `Environment variables` of your web app. As mentioned in [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-github-actions?tabs=applevel#generate-deployment-credentials).

> As of October 2020, Linux web apps will need the app setting  `WEBSITE_WEBDEPLOY_USE_SCM`  set to  `true`  **before downloading the publish profile**. This requirement will be removed in the future.

My directory

```yaml
my-repo
|--.github/workflows
|   |--main_flaskappbackend.yml
|--backend
    |--app.py
    |--requirements.txt
|--frontend
```

[image]

**`main_flaskappbackend.yml`:**

```yaml
# Docs for the Azure Web Apps Deploy action: https://github.com/Azure/webapps-deploy
# More GitHub Actions for Azure: https://github.com/Azure/actions
# More info on Python, GitHub Actions, and Azure App Service: https://aka.ms/python-webapps-actions

name: Build and deploy Python app to Azure Web App - flaskappbackend

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Python version
        uses: actions/setup-python@v1
        with:
          python-version: '3.11'

      - name: Create and start virtual environment and Install Dependencies
        run: |
          python -m venv venv
          source venv/bin/activate
        working-directory: ./backend

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: pip install -r requirements.txt
        working-directory: ./backend
      
      
      - name: Upload artifact for deployment jobs
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: python-app
          path: |
            ./backend 
            !venv/

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: python-app
          path: ./backend


      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        with:
          app-name: 'flaskappbackend'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_4A1C3ED9993843D4A87E0CCFAB61604D }}
          package: ./backend
```

**`app.py`:**

```py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
  return "hello! this is a flask app"

if __name__=='__main__':
  app.run()
```

**`Output`:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly!!! I think the special env variable and path to backend in my `Deploy to Azure Web App` step was what I was missing! :)

I did however have to update my path and working directory to `backend/` instead of what you had `./backend`. When I had `./backend` I got a deployment error of `Deployment Failed, Package deployment using ZIP Deploy failed. Refer logs for more details.`

Comment: @rachelyw I am glad it helped you. :)